# Hair from one face

Tags: particles, hair

I have a problem with emitting hairs from only one face. For example, I have a cube. I want to emit hair only from the front face. I made a vertex group, where I asigned the front face. Next I made a particles system of hair and selected density to my vertex group. But the problem is that hair emitts from the front face and from the faces connected to the front. The back face is without hair. I found out that in the weight paint the front face is red and the faces cennected to it are gradually blue. But the substraction doesn't work, either. When I substract on the corner verticle of the cube, part of the front face become blue, too. What should I do? Thanks for answers :)